# Store configs per feature branch without committing

Tags: git, mobile, jenkins, automation

We are converting our mobile project to git, and as such are planning to have each feature branch codebase have its own build created, that means build per feature.

Due to this we need do various things such as generate the icon with an appropriate text to make it easy for the QA to identify which APK they are opening, have each feature point to different web backends (as each web backend is also build per feature, so the url differs). Now we can easily have the developers commit all of this to each feature branch, this would work fine until the developer submits a merge request. When a developer submits a merge request this unwanted URL and other paramters unique to each feature would be merged to the mainline. Now we do not wan't that.

What we thought of was having a branch naming convention with the PT number, and jenkins when building would identify the branch name and thereafter call a remote web service with the PT number as the key to get all of the relevant metadata such as which web service URL that PT should use then. Also one question in addition is where do we store the data (e.g. : google docs excel sheet). What would be the best way of doing this and such.

Comment: We use Git with Jenkins and never had the need to have separate icons for each build.

Comment: That is just one example of things being parameterized, we have other stuff as well. Do you have any other parameterizations

Comment: I am not completely clear on what your needs are, but Jenkins out of the box serves our needs pretty well.  There are a ton of plugins as well if you want to go in that direction.

Comment: So you have to do a bit of one-time manual work per branch. You do a merge from the feature to the mainline, but you do it manually and do not copy over the icon etc. Then you push that merge to the mainline. Subsequent merges only pick up changes so they do not pick up the icon etc. You could even do this as part of branch creation process.